# Looping within switch statements

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

I am wondering what the most efficient method for looping within a switch statement would be. Below I have a userInput variable and would like suggestions if an if/then statement would be better implemented here to continue my menu selection until -1 is entered to exit my program, or if a do/while loop would be more appropriate.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VirtualZoo
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
// Options
final int catType = 0,
          dogType = 1,
          duckType = 2,
          exit = -1;

// create Scanner
Scanner input;
input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo");
                System.out.println("Pick select an animal to visit");
    System.out.println("=================================");
    System.out.println("===========MAIN MENU=============");
    System.out.println("=================================");
    System.out.println("==  " + catType + ") Cat    ===================");
    System.out.println("==  " + dogType + ") Dog    ===================");
    System.out.println("==  " + duckType + ") Duck   ===================");
    System.out.println("== " + exit + ") EXIT   ===================");
    System.out.println("=================================");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "Input  : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = sc.nextInt();

Animal animalSelected = null;

switch (userInput) 
{
    case 0:
        animalSelected = new Cat();
        break;
    case 1:
        animalSelected = new Dog();
        break;
    case 2:
        animalSelected = new Duck();
        break;
    case -1:
        System.out.println("\n" + "Thank you for visiting the Virtual Zoo" + "\n" + "Goodbye!");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if (animalSelected != null)
 {
    System.out.println(animalSelected);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: if then switch wont loop your execution. it will be just single pass. So whats the problem?

Comment: My issue is that I tried implementing a do while loop so that if the userInput, when -1 was selected, would exit my program, but if any other number is selected 0-2 the program would prompt you to select another animal. I basically want an infinite loop until the user decides to exit, but the do while did not work with my final if statement.

Comment: but you are showing me the code that has no loops at al

Comment: so why domt ylu first unvlude your not working at all loop and the askwhy it is not working and how to fix that. right now your code "works fine"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this cases a do-while loop would be the best one. I will write your code with a do-while loop here, please let me know if it is what you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VirtualZoo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Options
        final int catType = 0,
                dogType = 1,
                duckType = 2,
                exit = -1;

// create Scanner
        Scanner input;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo");
        System.out.println("Pick select an animal to visit");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("===========MAIN MENU=============");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("==  " + catType + ") Cat    ===================");
        System.out.println("==  " + dogType + ") Dog    ===================");
        System.out.println("==  " + duckType + ") Duck   ===================");
        System.out.println("== " + exit + ") EXIT   ===================");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Input  : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            userInput = sc.nextInt();

            Animal animalSelected = null;

            switch (userInput) {
                case 0:
                    animalSelected = new Cat();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    animalSelected = new Dog();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    animalSelected = new Duck();
                    break;
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("\n" + "Thank you for visiting the Virtual Zoo" + "\n" + "Goodbye!");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (animalSelected != null) {
                System.out.println(animalSelected);
            }
        } while (userInput != -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that is what I was going to try but every time I would code the while(userInput != -1); I would get a runtime error. I must have misplaced it in the structure. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, I did run the same code and got no exception, copy/paste the exception you see in the logs here if you need more help. And mark the answer as correct if it is please. have fun bro

Answer (score 1):

A do while loop would be suitable as you always want to run the switch case at least one time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a do-while loop is better in this case as you want this to run more than once. An if/else statement wont solve your problem that easily